# jQuery.load() not executed with Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to develop Tabs functionality by links in MVC project with below code -

```
@{
    var ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions
                          {
                              HttpMethod = "POST",
                              InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                              UpdateTargetId = "contentPanel",                                   
                              OnComplete = "EnhanceGui",
                              OnFailure = "HandleError"
                          };
}

// This generates link and clicking it load other partial view
@Ajax.ActionLink("Users", "Users", "Admin", ajaxOptions)
```

**Problem** - How to make jQuery load() events to be executed when user click on link?

I am aware about Ajax working that it doesn't load script and only update specific area. *But is there no other way for making it possible?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **@Ajax.ActionLink** replaces content of *UpdateTargetId*, I planned to put my scripts (jquery and custom scripts) in each ***partial view*** as follow -

```
@model System.Collections.IEnumerable

<div class="block-title">
<h2 class="h2Users">Users</h2>
</div>
<div class="block-body">    
<div class="padTop10">
    @Html.Partial("_GridViewPartial", Model)
</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/prAdmin") // SCRIPTS WILL BE ADDED IN MAIN PAGE
</div>
```

Now all scripts are available for each partial view, all functionality depending on script works smoothly.